# SQL statement not receiving variable definition

Tags: php, pdo, private

In this script there are two sql statements , the first one handles all the txt fields and PDO gets a row id:

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId():
```

The second sql statement is inside a private class and should insert the URL of the two files into the same row (as the first statement did).

The first sql statement is executing fine.
The second one is not and I think it's because it's not understanding what $last_id is.

Any suggestions to get the second PDO working?

```
 <?php
require('../dbcon2.php');
//Connection 1
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO listings (title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment, transaction, date_added) VALUES (:title, :address, :lot_size, :zoning, :build_size, :sale_price, :lease_price, :comment, :transaction, now())");
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
          $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lot_size', $_POST['lot_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':zoning', $_POST['zoning']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':build_size', $_POST['build_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':sale_price', $_POST['sale_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lease_price', $_POST['lease_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
 $conn = null;
 //Create class
    class CropAvatar {
        private $src;
        private $data;
        private $file;
        private $dst;
        private $type;
        private $extension;
        private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
        private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
        private $msg;

function __construct($src, $data, $file, $last_id) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setId($last_id);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
}
        private $last_id;
        public function setId($last_id) {
                 $this->id = $last_id;
}
        private function setSrc($src) {
            if (!empty($src)) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($src);
                if ($type) {
                    $this -> src = $src;
                    $this -> type = $type;
                    $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $this -> setDst();
                }
            }
        }
        private function setData($data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
            }
        }
        private function setFile($file) {
            $errorCode = $file['error'];
            if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
                if ($type) {
                    $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777);
                    }
                    $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                    $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                        if (file_exists($src)) {
                            unlink($src);
                        }
                        $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
                        $listing_img="http://www." . $Website . ".com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
  //Process file upload 
                        $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
                        $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                        $extensionf = end($tempf);
                        if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
                        && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
                        && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
                        {
                            $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                            if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
                            {
                            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
                            }   
                                else 
                                {
                                    if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                                    {
                                     echo $_FILES["flyer"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                                    }
                                        else 
                                        {
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                                         }
                                }
                        $ad_link="http://www." . $Website . ".com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
      //Connection 2
      try {
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $sql="UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$last_id";
          $conn->exec($sql);
          }
      catch(PDOException $e)
          {
          echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
          }
      $conn = null;
          }
      //Error handling
                        if ($result) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = $extension;
                            $this -> setDst();
                        } else {
                             $this -> msg = 'Failed to save file';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
            }
        }

        private function setDst() {
            $dir = $this -> dstDir;

            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
            }

            $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
        }

        private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
            if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                        break;
                }

                if (!$src_img) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                    return;
                }

                $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
                $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);

                if ($result) {
                    switch ($this -> type) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!$result) {
                        $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
                }

                imagedestroy($src_img);
                imagedestroy($dst_img);
            }
        }
        private function codeToMessage($code) {
            switch ($code) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                    $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                    $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                    break;

                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                    $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                    break;

                default:
                    $message = 'Unknown upload error';
            }

            return $message;
        }

        public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }

        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $last_id);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: you should NEVER go directly from the `$_POST` array to a bound parameter. Even if you're using PDO.

Comment: you mean this $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); ?

Comment: yes, in regards to your question though in your update statement you used `$last_id` rather than `$this->id` -> change this `UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$last_id` to `UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id`

Comment: @iamde_coder post this as an answer this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your update statement you used `$last_id` rather than `$this->id`

change this:

```
UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$last_id
```

to:

```
UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id
```